# scp connection via ssh refused, but connection via ssh works

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

I want to copy the file from MS-windows: `D:/myfolder/b.csv` to virtualbox Gnu/Linux `/home/tester/Downloads`

I can connect via ssh:
`ssh tester@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`

but scp can't:
`scp D:/myfolder/b.csv tester@127.0.0.1:2222/home/tester/Downloads/b.csv`

> ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
>   lost connection

Comment: That is not how you specify the port. (there is a clue in the error message)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you didn't specified the port like you did when ssh-ing. Use `scp -P 2222 ...`